# part of linked list not printing

Tags: c++

So I'm working on a linked list code and I have two functions: one to build the list forward and one to build the list backward. 
My code runs but the problem I am having is that it is only printing out the function to `buildlistForward()` but not `buildlistBackward()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream fin;
//ofstream fout;
struct nodeType
{
    int num;
    nodeType *next;
};
void buildlistForward();
void buildlistBackward();
//void deleteHead(nodeType);
int main()
{
    fin.open("testscores_input.txt");
    buildlistForward();
    buildlistBackward();

    return 0;
}
void buildlistForward()
{
    nodeType *head = NULL, *trail = NULL, *current = NULL;
    int digit;
    cout << "The list built forward is: " << endl;
    while (fin >> digit)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = new nodeType;
            head->num = digit;
            head->next = NULL;
            trail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            current = new nodeType;
            current->num = digit;
            current->next = NULL;
            trail->next = current;
            trail = current;
        }
    }
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        cout << current->num << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
void buildlistBackward()
{
    nodeType *head1 = NULL, *current1;
    int digit;
    cout << "The list built backward is: " << endl;
    while (fin >> digit)
    {
        if (head1 == NULL)
        {
            head1 = new nodeType;
            head1->num = digit;
            head1->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            current1 = new nodeType;
            current1->num = digit;
            current1->next = NULL;
            current1->next = head1;
            head1 = current1;
        }
    }
    current1 = head1;
    while (current1 != NULL)
    {
        cout << current1->num << endl;
        current1 = current1->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Once `buildlistForward()` has finished, you've reached the end of the file and there's no more data left to read.

Comment: You interleave *printing* with *modifying* datastructures. That's more or less asking for trouble. Please rewrite your code: introduce a `print` method or something equivalent. Separate responsibilities.

Comment: Are you sure that `buildlistForward()` finishes in the first place?

Comment: so what exactly would i need to do to be able to use the data in buildlistForward in my other function?

Answer (score 0):

The program does `buildlistForward()` first so when the end of the file is read there is nothing to read into for `buildlistBackward()` you would need to read from the file again by opening the ifstream, however you could also just print the linked list backwards by implementing a tail, and accessing the last `node` and print each from last to first, rather than reading the input and printing as each node is inputted.